# How to print out possible string with alphabet set and length?

Tags: java

I am using java

For example, the following situation:

First, the function is used as a print all possible strings.

```java
char[] alphabetSet = "012abc".toCharArray();
int length =5;

Output:
0,1,2,a,b,c,01,02,0a,0b,0c,10,11,12,1a ..................... ccccc. stop in length = 5
```

Then, I want to add a loop stopper to fetch the specified string.

```java
char[] alphabetSet = "012abc".toCharArray();
int length =5;
int loopStopper = 3;

Output:
a
```

Thank you

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backtracking.

```
void print_all(char []ch,int maxLen){
     for(int i=1;i<=maxLen;i++)
        backTrack(ch,i,0,new char[i]);
}
void backTrack(char[] ch,int len,int k,char[] ans){
    if(k==len){
        System.out.print(new String(ans,0,len)+",");
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++){
            ans[k]=ch[i];
            backTrack(ch,len,k+1,ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then, I want to add a loop stopper to fetch the specified string. How do I add a checkpoint to break the loop? Please read the question that has been updated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String alphabet = "012abc";// for example as your code "012abc"
        char[] alphabetSet = alphabet.toCharArray();
        int length = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSet.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(alphabetSet[i] + ",");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSet.length; i++) {
                System.out.printf("%d%c,",j,alphabetSet[i]);
            }
        }
```